# Linq join where clause not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, join, where-clause

I have this mssql query, I want to convert to linq

```
select * from personas
left join PersonaDocumento on PersonaDocumento.PersonaId=personas.Id
where personas.FirstName='23895389' or PersonaDocumento.Documento='23895389'
```

This does not work:

```
from p in db.personas
join d in db.PersonaDocumento on p.Id equals d.PersonaId into dj1
where p.FirstName=='23895389' || dj1.Documento=='23895389'
from d in dj1.DefaultIfEmpty()
select p
```

Comment: In the future, please elaborate on the phrase "does not work".

Answer (score 0):

I think you made three mistakes there:

```
from p in db.personas
join d in db.PersonaDocumento on p.Id equals d.PersonaId into dj1
where p.FirstName=='Jzuan' 
from d in dj1.DefaultIfEmpty()
where d.Documento=='23895389' 
select d
```

First was `join d on` where the correct syntax is `in`. Second you were selecting from p and not from the table you have joined into which is `d`.
Plus `dj1` is a list of elements, so if you need to filters elements in it you should do it after. Specifically in the from `d` in `dj1` clause

Comment: I mistyped, but the where clause  " dj1.Documento=='23895389'" does not work at all.

Comment: Hard to tell, please add the definitions of your tables to ur questions

Comment: The problem , It's not related to database definition , I think, is that linq does not support any field of the join within the where clause.

Comment: I edited my answer. dj1 is a list as output of the join clause

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
from p in db.personas
join d in db.PersonaDocumento on p.Id equals d.PersonaId into dj1
from ld in dj1.DefaultIfEmpty()
where p.FirstName=='Jzuan' || (ld != null && ld.Documento=='23895389')
select p
```

Notice how I reordered clauses.